# What is the best way to include my own data in an event in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, events, event-handling, wxwidgets

I am trying to implement file-like structure. File and Folder names are displayed in ListBox.

I want to  add additional data to ListBox entries - now it has only it's string, I want it to have a bool to differentiate between folders and files, so when I double click and `OnDoubleClick(wxCommandEvent&)` method which I have bound to this event is called I can access the additional data.

I know I can create custom Events or subclass existing ones but how can I customize ListBox to hold more data?

Comment: maybe you should look at wxListCtrl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wxListBox derives from [wxItemContainer](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_item_container.html) which means that it allows each item to hold an extra piece of data. For example, you can define a client data class like this:

```
class MyClientData:public wxClientData
{
public:
    enum ItemType
    {
        ItemTypeInvalid,
        File,
        Folder
    };

    MyClientData(ItemType it):m_itemType(it){}
    ItemType GetItemType() const{return m_itemType;}

private:
    ItemType m_itemType;
};
```

You can then attach the client data to the listbox items when you append them to the control like this:

```
listbox->Append("Folder 1", new MyClientData(MyClientData::Folder));
listbox->Append("Folder 2", new MyClientData(MyClientData::Folder));
listbox->Append("File 1", new MyClientData(MyClientData::File));
listbox->Append("File 2", new MyClientData(MyClientData::File));
listbox->Append("File 3", new MyClientData(MyClientData::File));
listbox->Append("File 4", new MyClientData(MyClientData::File));
listbox->Append("No Client Data 1");
```

Since MyClientData is derived from [wxClientData](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_client_data.html), the listbox will take ownership of the client data objects and delete them in its destructor or when the items are deleted from the control.

You can recover the client data in the `OnDoubleClick` method (assuming that method is handling the `wxEVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK` event for your listbox) like this:

```
void xxx::OnDoubleClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    int itemNo = event.GetSelection();
    wxListBox* listBox = wxDynamicCast(event.GetEventObject(), wxListBox);
    MyClientData* clientData = NULL;

    if ( listBox != NULL && itemNo != wxNOT_FOUND )
    {
        clientData=static_cast<MyClientData*>(listBox->GetClientObject(itemNo));
    }

    ... do something with clientData here ...
}
```

Finally, as Igor said, I'm not sure wxListBox is the best control to use here. [wxListCtrl](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html) or [wxDataViewListCtrl](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_list_ctrl.html) would probably look better. Those controls are a little more complicated and do not derive from wxItemContainer. However, you can still attach extra data with for example `wxListCtrl::SetItemPtrData`, but you'll have to clean up any dynamically created objects yourself.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like exactly what I was looking for! Also I will check out wxListCtrl and wxDataViewListCtrl, it might come in handy later. Thanks a lot!